# SHKFacebook handleDidBecomeActive - no knows class method for selector

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I'm trying to get Sharekit Facebook sharing to work. Step 7 in the [manual](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) states that these methods should be implemented:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [SHKFacebook handleDidBecomeActive];
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [SHKFacebook handleWillTerminate];
}
```

But XCode gives me an error that `handleDidBecomeActive` and `handleWillTerminate` are not class methods of `SHKFacebook`.

Anyidea what I might have done wrong? I linked ShareKit with Cocoapods.

Comment: Might it be, that these are legacy methods, that are not needed anymore? Sharing FB seems to work fine without them.